# How To Install Intel Linux Drivers in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: intel-graphics, intel

I have search all around but didn't find any **Intel Linux Drivers for Ubuntu 13.04**

Only supported version is 12.04 & 12.10

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intel-linux-graphics-installer

so is there any way I can install Intel Drivers on Ubuntu 13.04 ?

As searching I have also read a comment on some blogs that **Drivers** are already included in Ubuntu 13.04 is it true ?

**Specs**

HD 3000 with NVidia Optimus

Comment: 13.04 comes with the latest drivers, you don't need to do anything further.

Comment: 1st of all ty ...and should I delete this question or leave it open so that all us know that its already included ?

Comment: Just leave it here and when it gets closed as a duplicate it will serve as a signpost for the next person who runs into in search, thanks!

Comment: okay got it ...

Comment: Trust me. You do NOT want to touch those. Unless there is something wrong, just leave the default drivers on. Many people I know tried this update method and it just messed up their system.

Comment: I m using it with the default one...thanks for the help...how can I messed up if you guys are here ...that's why I asked...